# Add a vertical line in the middle of a view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to add a vertical line between two divs. I'm using bootstrap so I have a .col-md-12 and then I have columns inside, one with .col-md-4(it has a form) and the another one with .col-md-8 (It has a table).

[image]

So it has to like this image.

I've tried using a hr and giving it a class and then rotate it with 90deg, it worked but it did not let me add the space at the bottom.
And I can not use an image.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: put a side border on one of the divs, with css?

Comment: how about using border-right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a classname for middle div and apply the border like this:

```
.middle{
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

---

For two columns div inside one column div you can apply border-right or border-left on one of them.

Answer (score 0):

choose the highest height of the column and put border-right to first column either border-left to second column which depends on the height.

other option you set image

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">...</div>
<div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs divider"></div>
<div class="col-md-7"></div>
</div>

.divider{
background: url("img/divider.png") repeat-y;
}
```